# How to execute foo = fun(foo) for many different variables in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

My question is related to reading MATLAB data into Python. The scipy.io would do this but many variables in MATLAB is in the shape n*1 or 1*m. Suppose I have variables with different names foo1, foo2, foo3, ... How should I apply foo = np.squeeze(foo) to each of these variables. Is there a way to deal with this problem without apply the spueeze function to every variable explicitly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `loadmat` gives a dictionary with all those variables.  You could iterate on the `keys`.  But yes, you will have to apply `squeeze` to each array - or write your `numpy` to work gracefully with either the 1d or the 2d version.  The matlab arrays might also have `F` order, though that should matter for the squeezable ones.

Comment: wait "many variables" or an array? It should be an array

Comment: Yeah iterate over keys is what I am thinking about. But how to execute var1 = squeeze(var1) with var1 being a string of the variable name?

Comment: It's easy enough to test that, isn't it?  Variables with string values aren't ready substitute for a var.

Comment: I mean, the iteration variable is key, which is the name of the variable, but I cannot do key = np.squeeze(key) in the iteration, right?

Comment: How are you getting these variables out of the `loadmat` dictionary in the first place?  But look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote created 3 variables in Octave and wrote them to a file:

```
In [854]: data = loadmat('test.mat')
In [855]: data
Out[855]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 4.0.0, 2017-11-08 02:28:22 UTC',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'x': array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.]]),
 'y': array([[ 1.,  3.,  6.,  4.,  6.]]),
 'z': array([[ 1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.]])}

In [856]: data['x'].shape
Out[856]: (1, 10)
In [857]: np.squeeze(data['x']).shape
Out[857]: (10,)
```

But a quick look at the `loadmat` docs shows `squeeze_me`:

```
In [861]: data = loadmat('test.mat', squeeze_me=True)
In [862]: data
Out[862]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 4.0.0, 2017-11-08 02:28:22 UTC',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'x': array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.]),
 'y': array([ 1.,  3.,  6.,  4.,  6.]),
 'z': array([[ 1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.]])}
```

---

Without `squeeze_me` we can still iterate on the keys

```
In [866]: for key in ['x','y']:
     ...:     data[key] = np.squeeze(data[key])
     ...:     
In [867]: data
Out[867]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 4.0.0, 2017-11-08 02:28:22 UTC',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'x': array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.]),
 'y': array([ 1.,  3.,  6.,  4.,  6.]),
 'z': array([[ 1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.]])}
```

I'm writing the squeeze array back to the `data` dictionary.  So I can use the same `key` string on both sides of the equation.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This solved my problem perfectly even though I was thinking about other solutions before.

Answer (score 0):

[`np.squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) takes an axis argument so you can pass that rather than iterate:

```
In [11]: a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3, 1)

In [12]: a
Out[12]:
array([[[0],
        [1],
        [2]],

       [[3],
        [4],
        [5]],

       [[6],
        [7],
        [8]]])

In [13]: np.squeeze(a, -1)
Out[13]:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

You can also do multiple axis at once:

```
In [21]: b = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 1, 3, 1)

In [22]: b
Out[22]:
array([[[[0],
         [1],
         [2]]],


       [[[3],
         [4],
         [5]]],


       [[[6],
         [7],
         [8]]]])

In [23]: np.squeeze(b, (1, 3))
Out[23]:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your promote help. But I was asking how to apply the squeeze to many variables with different names. Any suggestion to that situation?